# ms sql server executes 'then' before 'when' in case

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

when i try to select

```
select    
case when (isnumeric(SUBSTRING([VZWECK2],1,9)) = 1) 
     then CONVERT(decimal,SUBSTRING([VZWECK2],1,9)) 
     else null 
     end as [NUM]
from table
```

sql-server gives me:

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 2
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```

`[VZWECK2]` is a char(27). is this a known bug? because it seems to me it executes the convert before it does the case, which defies the purpose of my select. i know that there are values that are not numeric obviously, which is why i need the case statement to weed them out.

for some reason selecting

```
select    
case when (isnumeric(SUBSTRING([VZWECK2],1,9)) = 1) 
     then 99
     else null 
     end as [NUM]
from table
```

yields no errors and behaves as expected

Comment: Are you sure is order of execution, not [`ISNUMERIC`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272(v=sql.110).aspx) returning true for data that cannot be converted to `decimal`? *ISNUMERIC returns 1 for some characters that are not numbers, such as plus (+), minus (-), and valid currency symbols such as the dollar sign ($).*

Comment: Also, data with comma is considered to be numeric, like `ISNUMERIC('123,12') = 1` , but `CONVERT(DECIMAL, '123,12')` fails

Comment: You should also specify precision/scale for your decimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `ISNUMERIC` is very forgiving, and that `ISNUMERIC` returns 1 is unfortunately no guarantee that `CONVERT` will work. This is why SQL Server 2012 and later introduced `TRY_CAST` and `TRY_CONVERT`.

If you are converting whole numbers, a more reliable check is to make sure the string consists of only digits with `NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'` (that is, it must not contain a non-digit anywhere). This is too restrictive for some formats (like floating point) but for integers it works nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know the value which throws the error? IsNumeric is not exactly fool-proof, for example:

```
select ISNUMERIC('$')
select ISNUMERIC('+')
select ISNUMERIC('-')
```

all yield 1

Alternatively, you could go with [TRY_PARSE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/manub22/archive/2013/12/24/use-new-try-parse-instead-of-isnumeric-sql-server-2012.aspx) instead.

Edit: TRY_PARSE is introduced in sql server 2012, so may not be available to you.